# LINQ to XML - Load node then add to Xdocument - Namespace issue

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, xml-namespaces

I am having serious trouble adding an XElement after loading that inherits the parent's namespace... I've tried multiple examples, set the exact same namespaces in both documents, tried removing the namespaces... this is honestly a mess, the only example I found was re-creating the XElement object with a namespace in the constructor but my XML is pretty massive. I do not wish to do this. Is there a way to Inherit namespaces after a load then add to parent (see code for example of what I mean).

```
xml = XDocument.Load(rdlFile);
var selectNode = xml.AssumeISelectedTheNodeIWantWithLinq();
//A static element loaded from a separate file
XElement elementNeedsNameSpace = XElement.Load("element.xml");
selectNode.Add(elementNeedsNameSpace );

//Output xml:
<MyAddedNode xmlns="">
  <AssumeLotsOfChilds>
    <SubChilds/>
  </AssumeLotsOfChilds>
</MyAddedNode>

//Root xml
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
```

If I remove the attribute then I get all the children messed up and receive the stupid xlmns="" :(

Comment: Try to define XNamespace 'ns = "..";' and add it with element 'selectNode.Add(ns + element);'

Comment: I like using following : xml.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "AssumeLotsOfChilds").  No namespace is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 'element loaded from a separate file' and children don't have a namespace, hence the addition of `xmlns=""` when they're inserted into a document that has a different default namespace.

If you want to get rid of that attribute then you need to change all the element names to use the default namespace of the document you are inserting it into:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition"

foreach (var element in elementNeedsNamespace.DescendantsAndSelf())
{
     element.Name = ns + element.Name.LocalName;
}

selectNode.Add(elementNeedsNameSpace);
```